# single-spa-angularjs microfrontend not loading html templateUrl for directives

Tags: angularjs, single-spa

I am trying to use single-spa library to combine two micro front ends one in angular and other in angularjs.

Everything is working fine when i don't use directive in angularjs which refer to templateUrl instead of template.

```
import "./styles.css";

import angular from "angular";
import singleSpaAngularJS from 'single-spa-angularjs';



const ngLifecycles = singleSpaAngularJS({
  angular: angular,
  mainAngularModule: 'myApp',
  uiRouter: false,
  ngRoute:true,
  preserveGlobal: false,
  template:'<div my-directive></div>'

 
  
 
});

export const bootstrap = ngLifecycles.bootstrap;
export const mount = ngLifecycles.mount;
export const unmount = ngLifecycles.unmount;




angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myController", function() {
  var vm = this;

  vm.heading = "Hi, this is AngularJS application running as microfrontEnd";
  vm.buttonClickCount = 0;

  vm.increaseCount = _increaseCount;

  function _increaseCount() {
    ++vm.buttonClickCount;
  }
}).directive("myDirective",function()
{
   return {
    restrict: 'A',
      controller:'myController',
      templateUrl: '../assets/templates/test-directive.html',
    controllerAs:'myCtrl'

   }


});
```

if i copy test-directive.html code inside template parameter and not use templateUrl parameter it works fine:

```
<div class="card-container1"><div  class="card1">
    <div>{{ myCtrl.heading }}</div>
    <div>Click Here: {{ myCtrl.buttonClickCount }}</div>
    <button ng-click="myCtrl.increaseCount()">Increase</button>
  </div></div>
```

I am getting error while loading the template from main shell... it is using root config app(main shell app) URL to search for template which is wrong. it should use angularjs frontend root url for it. How to fix it. For angular application(not AngularJS) using web pack.. there is a solution i see in the documentation. How to solve this issue for angularjs?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but you'll need to do a couple things:

1. Assuming you're using webpack, Use systemjs-webpack-interop to set your webpack public path on the fly. It should be the name of your single-spa application so myApp or @org/myApp or whatever you've called your angularjs app. This can be done in your webpack config or by creating a basepath.config file and import/require it at the very top of your entry file. The documentation is easy to follow.
2. Make sure you're using html-loader in your webpack config. Then for your templates (app/route templates or directives change templateUrl to template:require('path to template')